# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why is my Tkinter image not working? It is in the same directory, all commands are right but I get the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist.

What's wrong?

```
fertig=tkinter.Tk()
fertig.title("Window")
text=tkinter.Label(fertig,text="Success")
text.pack()
w = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="/Users/Hannes/Desktop/Spambot/successful.gif ")
w = tkinter.label(fertig,image=w)
w.pack()
knapp=tkinter.Button(fertig,text="Ok",command=lambda:close())
knapp.pack()
knapp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sounds like it can't find your image file. I just noticed there's a space character at the very end of `"/Users/Hannes/Desktop/Spambot/successful.gif "`—maybe that's the problem (assuming the file does indeed exist). Also, try removing the `file=` part, just pass the path string as a regular positional argument.

Comment: but doesn't tkinter needs the file= ?

Comment: It's unclear to me. For goodness sake, just try it...

Comment: If your script is in the same directory as the image, you can just use ```tkinter.PhotoImage(file="successful.gif ")```. Using a relative path rather than an absolute one can be desirable since you can run the code on different machines without the exact same directory structure (or as a user other that Hannes for example).

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly give the error you say it does, because there's a syntax error on the sixth line. You also have the problem that your filename ends with a space which, while possible on linux, is extraordinarily unlikely to be the actual name. When I fix those two problems, your code works fine for me.

Comment: @NextTV:  yes, tkinter needs the `file=`.

Comment: @martineau: the first positional argument to `PhotoImage` is not the path. Removing `file=` will not work.

Comment: @Bryan: I was confusing it with you pass it a `PIL.Image` object (in which case you don't need the `file=` on the argument). If what you say about needing it to pass a file name argument is true, why isn't the OP's example code working?

Comment: @martineau: _"why isn't the OP's example code working"_ - I don't know. They didn't post code that reproduces the problem. My guess is, it's because of the space after the filename (`"...gif "`), but that wouldn't give the error they say it does. Either they are misrepresenting the error, or they are misrepresenting the code.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me on my Windows system. I had to fix and add a few (unrelated) things to get the code in your question to work, but after doing so I found the real reason the image doesn't display.

So, the error that relates most directly to the that problem is because you're overwriting the variable `w`: After you assign a `tkinter.PhotoImage()` value to it, you immediately assign a another value (the `tkinter.Label`) to using its current value (`image=w`). The second assignment causes the `tkinter.PhotoImage()` object that was in it to be lost. Since there are no more references to to, it will be garbage-collected at some point.

To fix that, I simply assign the `PhotoImage` object to a separate variable `img`.

Note, too, that (apparently) having the trailing space character in the filename isn't a problem (at least not on Windows).

Here's some "official" [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) specifically about the `PhotoImage` class that discusses the need for keeping a reference around to the original—see the **NOTE:** at the end—when using it with other tkinter widgets (like a `Label`).

```
import tkinter

def close():  # just a placeholder implementation.
    print('close() called')

fertig=tkinter.Tk()
fertig.title("Window")
text=tkinter.Label(fertig, text="Success")
text.pack()
#w = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="/Users/Hannes/Desktop/Spambot/successful.gif ")
img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\vols\Files\PythonLib\Stack Overflow\successful.gif ")
w = tkinter.Label(fertig, image=img)
w.pack()
knapp=tkinter.Button(fertig, text="Ok", command=lambda: close())
knapp.pack()
knapp.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like (using an image of my own).

[image: screenshot of script running and show an image]

Comment: Yes... the program itself is working but if i put it in the program where it should be i get the same error....

Comment: @Next TV: I can only fix the code in your question—which I have not only done, but have also explained the main problem. Expecting any more is unreasonable and unfair in my opinion.

Comment: I don't blame you for answering a questin i didn't ask, you help me alot with what you have doen! Thanks again!